# Azure Active directory login page and Xframe issue

Tags: javascript, azure, iframe

We have an Azure website with Authentication/Authorization enabled on the site connecting to Active Directory. The app in the browser redirects to default login page and works fine.

The same login page fails to load in SalesForce canvas app as the SF canvas app loads the page in the iframe.

The page is throwing following error in the browser

Refused to display 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/dc5133dd-ee6e-4110-a50c-ddb882f6e7e3/oaut….aspx%26b2cPolicy%3D&nonce=ccd2336c376c400c94a820cc08945250_20170202084203' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

Any alternate approach to load the default AAD login page in iframe will be helpful.

Comment: Are you testing your application in IE on local? And what's the version of adal for js you are using? At the issue should be fixed in 1.0.11 refer at https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/94